# Rails Modal Form - Can't Get Validation Errors to Display in Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, modal-dialog

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention I am using validation at the model level, and that works fine. So the validations are preventing the modal form from being submitted (and ajax:error is getting called), but I'm having no luck dealing with the resulting errors object and properly displaying the errors. For now I'm just using placeholder text ("FORM HAS ERRORS"). Again, validations and displaying errors are working fine with my non-modal (non-ajax) forms (where I'm using the error messages partial). I really wish I could just render that partial in my modal dialog box, which you would think would be simple.

I'm pulling my hair out over this.

I have an "add tour" form, and within that form you can select buildings from the database to add to the tour (I'm using jquery tokeninput to search for and select buildings). All that works great.

I added the ability for the user to add a new building by providing a "Add Building" link, which brings up a modal form. I process the results and everything works great (building gets saved, modal gets dismissed, token gets added, etc).

Everything works great except validation in the modal form . . . which doesn't work at all. I've tried client_side_validations, I've tried writing coffee script to iterate through the error object returned by the controller, etc.

Anyway, I've tried everything I know to try, so now I'm coming to you guys for help. For now I just have placeholder error-handling code in the coffeescript file (that just displays "FORM HAS ERRORS" in a very rudimentary way). I took out all my previous attempts at making this work because it was getting ugly, and I'm really just looking for the best way to do this.

Here are the pertinent files.

building.js.coffee

```
$ ()->
  $("form.new_building").on "ajax:success", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("form.new_building")[0].reset()
    $('#new-building-modal').modal('hide')
    fulladdress = "#{data.address} (#{data.name}, #{data.city}, #{data.zip})"
    $('#tour_building_tokens').tokenInput("add", {id: data.id, address: fulladdress} )

  $("form.new_building").on "ajax:error", (event, xhr, status, error) ->
    $('#display_errors').append('<font color="red"><strong>FORM HAS ERRORS</strong></font><br><br>')
    $('#display_errors').show()
```

buildings_controller.rb

```
....

def create
    @building = Building.new(params[:building])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @building.save
        format.html { redirect_to @building, notice: 'Building Created!' }
        format.json { render json: @building, status: :created, location: @building }
      else
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @building.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Add Tour') %>

<h1>Add Tour</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(@tour) do |f| %>

            <%= render 'fields', f: f %>

            <%= link_to 'Add Building', '#new-building-modal', 'data-toggle' => "modal" %>

            </br>
            </br>

            <%= f.submit "Add Tour", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>


<div id='new-building-modal' class='modal hide fade'>


            <div class = "modal-body">

                <%= form_for(Building.new, remote:true, html: {"data-type" => :json}) do |f| %>

                    <div id="display_errors" style="display:none;">
                    </div>

                    <%= f.label :name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :name %>

                    <%= f.label :address %>
                    <%= f.text_field :address %>

                    <%= f.label :city %>
                    <%= f.text_field :city %>

                    <%= f.label :zip %>
                    <%= f.text_field :zip %>

            </div>

            <div class = "modal-footer">

                    <%= f.submit "Add Building", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
            </div>

                <% end %>
</div>
```

Oh, and I also have a shared error messages partial that I'm not using with this modal right now (because I couldn't get the modal to "refresh" to display the errors). In a perfect world I'd use this same partial with the modal, because it works great with my other non-modal forms.

Here is the partial (again, not rendering this currently in the above code).

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <% if msg != "Password digest can't be blank" %>
                <li>* <%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide. I need as much detail as possible. I've researched related questions on Stack Overflow, and every time I think I'm close, I come up empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [muttonlamb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849245/muttonlamb) for pointing me in the right direction. I was 50% sure it had to do something with parsing the JSON, and he convinced me to stay on that path. Ironically it was [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323620/rails-3-unobtrusive-javascript-handle-json-response) that helped me get to the final answer. The answer to that question, which involved printing the error to the console, was what I was looking for. It turns out that it wasn't so much that I was parsing the error wrong . . . I was parsing the wrong object. Here is the final implementation that works . . .

new coffeescript (notice how I show, hide, and clear the div as necessary):

```
$ ()->
  $("form.new_building").on "ajax:success", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("form.new_building")[0].reset()
    $('#new-building-modal').modal('hide')
    fulladdress = "#{data.address} (#{data.name}, #{data.city}, #{data.zip})"
    $('#tour_building_tokens').tokenInput("add", {id: data.id, address: fulladdress} )
    $('#error_explanation').hide()

  $("form.new_building").on "ajax:error", (event, xhr, status, error) ->
    errors = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
    errorcount = errors.length
    $('#error_explanation').empty()
    if errorcount > 1
      $('#error_explanation').append('<div class="alert alert-error">The form contains ' + errorcount + ' errors.</div>')
    else
      $('#error_explanation').append('<div class="alert alert-error">The form contains 1 error</div>')
    $('#error_explanation').append('<ul>')
    for e in errors
      $('#error_explanation').append('<li>' + e + '</li>')
    $('#error_explanation').append('</ul>')
    $('#error_explanation').show()
```

new view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Add Tour') %>

<h1>Add Tour</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(@tour) do |f| %>

            <%= render 'fields', f: f %>

            <%= link_to 'New Building', '#new-building-modal', 'data-toggle' => "modal" %>

            </br>
            </br>

            <%= f.submit "Add Tour", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>


<div id='new-building-modal' class='modal hide fade'>

            <div class = "modal-header">
                <div id="error_explanation" style="display:none;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "modal-body">

                <%= form_for(Building.new, remote:true, html: {"data-type" => :json}) do |f| %>

                    <%= f.label :name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :name %>

                    <%= f.label :address %>
                    <%= f.text_field :address %>

                    <%= f.label :city %>
                    <%= f.text_field :city %>

                    <%= f.label :zip %>
                    <%= f.text_field :zip %>

            </div>

            <div class = "modal-footer">

                    <%= f.submit "Add Building", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
            </div>

                <% end %>
</div>
```

new controller:

```
def create
     @building = Building.new(params[:building])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @building.save
        format.html { redirect_to @building, notice: 'Building Created!' }
        format.json { render json: @building, status: :created, location: @building }
      else
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @building.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
  end
```

Finally, to keep the modal from scrolling when the errors are added (I wanted it to auto-resize instead), I added this CSS:

```
#new-building-modal {
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

Hope all these details prevent someone else from having to waste nearly a week on silly modal validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like your ajax request error section does not run.

The reason is this, the error you're looking for would be something like 'page not found' or some other HTTP error.

In your controller, the HTTP request will still be successful, i.e. it will still return data.

Your logic for handling whether errors are present should be in the ajax success block.

Hope this makes sense

```
$ ()->
  $("form.new_building").on "ajax:success", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("form.new_building")[0].reset()
    $('#new-building-modal').modal('hide')
    fulladdress = "#{data.address} (#{data.name}, #{data.city}, #{data.zip})"
    $('#tour_building_tokens').tokenInput("add", {id: data.id, address: fulladdress} )
```

You need to be checking for the error variable in this section.

Comment: That is what I thought at first too, but I added that "FORM HAS ERRORS" generic error message, and it is getting called when the validation triggers errors. So, the ajax error section is being called. However, I'm having no luck working with the errors object returned by the controller (which I guess would contain JSON?).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ has some good info on actually updating your view based on returned JSON.